# Deterministic Finite-state Automaton Questions

Tags: math, set, theory, set-theory

I have this DFA described as (Q, q1, A, N, F) where

> Q = {1,2,3,4},
>   q1 = 1,
>   A = {a,b,c},
>   F = {2,4},
>   N = {
>   (1,a) -> 2, (1,b) -> 3, (1,c) -> 4,
>   (2,a) -> 2, (2,b) -> 4,
>   (3,a) -> 2, (3,c) -> 4,
>   (4,b) -> 4, (4,c) -> 4 }

So I have drawn the transition diagram, and that looks fine,

I then need to work out wether or not the following strings are acceptable by this DFA:

1. aabbcc
2. acacac
3. cabbac
4. babbab

and come up with the following

1. Correct
2. Incorrect (can not move from a -> c ?)
3. Incorrect (can not move from c -a ? )
4. Incorrect (cannot move from b -> a)

I am not 100% sure those are correct, but think they are on the right track.

I then need to describe the language this accepts, in english, which I do not see being a problem, but where I need help is describing this language using mathematical notation. Could you please help me to understand this.

Thanks so much for your help

Comment: What would your description in English be?

Comment: Strictly speaking, this isn't a DFA. Are we to assume that the transitions you are missing lead to an undefined "dead" state? In any event, given a properly-defined DFA, you can find a regular expression using the second part of Kleene's theorem; see http://www.cs.odu.edu/~toida/nerzic/390teched/regular/fa/kleene-2.html . All that being said, if you can easily describe this in English, not being able to translate to mathematical notation might be a sign of a more serious shortcoming in your preparation for this course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answers about the strings acceptability are right, this can easily be seen by trying to follow them out in the diagram.
Now, about the language:

In the 2-nd vertex we can finish with the words corresponding following regular expression:
`b?a+` - we can optionally obtain `b` my moving to 3-rd vertex first, and then pass over `a`, or we can move to 2-nd vertex by `a` at once, and there we can add as much `a`s as we want.

Now about finishing the word in the 4-th vertex:

First, how can we reach vertex 4 ? 
 1. We can first time reach vertex 4 by moving there by `c` at once, or by moving to 3-rd vertex first, obtaining b, and then to 4-th by `c`. Hereby we get strings like `b?c`
2. We can reach vertex 2 with `b?a+` (as described in previous case), and then pass over `b`. Hereby we get strings like `b?a+b`.
Totally, we can reach to 4-th vertex with any word matching the `b?(a+b|c)` regexp.

Now, adding arbitrary count of `b` and `c` symbols in the end on vertex 4, we get the answer for this case:
`b?(a+b|c)(bc)*`

Finally, we can result the whole set of words acceptable by this DFA words as the following regex:

`b?( a+ | (a+b|c)(bc)*? )`